# How Snappy Compression Algorithm Works

Tags: c, compression, snappy, lossless-compression

I want to implement a version of snappy algorithm written in C for linux, but I need to understeand deeply how the algorithm works before reading the source-code becouse I think it's complex.

The problem is that I found very few technical documentation that describes deeply the process of the algorithm (compression and dec-).

Does someone can explain me how the algorithm works? Maybe with examples? Or just recommend me some book, pdf or whatever to understeand each step of this algorithm? (except wikipedia pages). Thanks a lot.

The algorithm is created by Google, based on Z77, byte-oriented.

Comment: If you're interested in an existing C port : [snappy-c](https://github.com/andikleen/snappy-c). In terms of something resembling a specification, there's [format_description.txt](https://github.com/google/snappy/blob/master/format_description.txt).

Comment: @dash-o the OP explicitely stated "except wikipedia pages"...

Comment: Thank you, @SanderDeDycker.